# How to print words that only cointain letters from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, comparison, iteration

Hello I have recently been trying to create a progam in Python 3 which will read a text file wich contains 23005 words, the user will then enter a **string of 9 characters** which the program will use to create words and compare them to the ones in the text file.

**I want to print words which contains between 4-9 letters and that also contains the letter in the middle of my list**. For example if the user enters the string "anitsksem" then the fifth letter "s" must be present in the word.

Here is how far I have gotten on my own:

```
# Open selected file & read
filen = open("svenskaOrdUTF-8.txt", "r")

# Read all rows and store them in a list
wordList = filen.readlines()

# Close File
filen.close()

# letterList index
i = 0
# List of letters that user will input
letterList = []
# List of words that are our correct answers
solvedList = []

# User inputs 9 letters that will be stored in our letterList
string = input(str("Ange Nio Bokstäver: "))
userInput = False

# Checks if user input is correct
while userInput == False:
   # if the string is equal to 9 letters
   # insert letter into our letterList.
   # also set userInput to True
    if len(string) == 9:
        userInput = True
        for char in string:
            letterList.insert(i, char)
            i += 1

    # If string not equal to 9 ask user for a new input
    elif len(string) != 9:
        print("Du har inte angivit nio bokstäver")
        string = input(str("Ange Nio Bokstäver: "))

# For each word in wordList
# and for each char within that word
# check if said word contains a letter from our letterList
# if it does and meets the requirements to be a correct answer
# add said word to our solvedList

for word in wordList:
    for char in word:
        if char in letterList:
            if len(word) >= 4 and len(word) <= 9 and letterList[4] in word:
                print("Char:", word)
                solvedList.append(word)
```

The issue that I run into is that instead of printing words which **only** contain letters from my `letterList`, it prints out words which contains **at least one** letter from my `letterList`. This also mean that some words are printed out multiple time, for example if the words contains multiple letters from `letterList`.

I've been trying to solve these problems for a while but I just can't seem to figure it out. I Have also tried using permutations to create all possible combinations of the letters in my list and then comparing them to my `wordlist`, however I felt that solution was to slow given the number of combinations which must be created.

```
    # For each word in wordList
    # and for each char within that word
    # check if said word contains a letter from our letterList
    # if it does and meets the requirements to be a correct answer
    # add said word to our solvedList
    for word in wordList:
        for char in word:
            if char in letterList:
                if len(word) >= 4 and len(word) <= 9 and letterList[4] in word:
                    print("Char:", word)
                    solvedList.append(word)
```

Also since I'm kinda to new to python, if you have any general tips to share, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get multiple words mainly because you iterate through each character in a given word and if that character is in the `letterList` you append and print it.

Instead, iterate on a word basis and not on a character basis while also using the `with` context managers to automatically close files:

```
with open('american-english') as f:
    for w in f:
        w = w.strip()
        cond = all(i in letterList for i in w) and letterList[4] in w
        if 9 > len(w) >= 4 and cond:
            print(w)
```

Here `cond` is used to trim down the `if` statement, `all(..)` is used to check if every character in the word is in `letterList`, `w.strip()` is to remove any redundant white-space.

Additionally, to populate your `letterList` when the input is `9` letters, *don't use `insert`*. Instead, just supply the string to `list` and the list will be created in a similar, but noticeably faster, fashion:

This:

```
if len(string) == 9:
    userInput = True
    for char in string:
        letterList.insert(i, char)
        i += 1
```

Can be written as:

```
if len(string) == 9:
    userInput = True
    letterList = list(string)
```

With these changes, the initial `open` and `readlines` are not needed, neither is the initialization of `letterList`.

Comment: Wow thank you the code looks much cleaner this way, however i still run into one issue. When the program prints out the results it prints out words that does not contain letters from letterList. for example if i use the string "anitsksem" i get words that contains letters like b, d, u etc. which are not in the letterList. How would i make sure that the words **only contain letters from the letterList**.

Comment: RIght, I missed that. Check out the updated version and see if it does what you're looking for @PeterYakob.

Comment: Thank you it works like a charm. Follow up question if you have time, if i wanted to only print out words that use a individual letter in the letterList **once** so e.g. if letterList = ["a", "n", "i", "b", "s", "l", "s", "y", "m"] the program would not print out words like: 'animal' since the letter 'a' only appears once in our list however if we have multiple occurences of a letter like 's' in the letterList example above we could print out: 'abyss'

Answer (score 0):

You can try this logic:

```
for word in wordList:
    # if not a valid work skip - moving this check out side the inner for-each will improve performance
    if len(word) < 4 or len(word) > 9 or letterList[4] not in word:
        continue
    # find the number of matching words
    match_count = 0
    for char in word:
        if char in letterList:
            match_count += 1
    # check if total number of match is equal to the word count
    if match_count == len(word):
        print("Char:", word)
        solvedList.append(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda functions to get this done.
I am just putting up a POC here leave it to you to convert it into complete solution.

```
filen = open("test.text", "r")
word_list = filen.read().split()
print("Enter your string")
search_letter = raw_input()[4]

solved_list  = [ word for word in word_list if  len(word) >= 4 and len(word) <= 9 and search_letter in word]
print solved_list
```

Comment: My answer Python27, so I had to use raw_input instead of input.